# Django Rest Framework - Efficient API Design

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, api-design

In any rest API,

1. Data comes in request body
2. We perform some Logic on
   data and perform some queries

3.finally API responds serialized data.

My question is :-
Where to put data processing Logic? And what is the efficient way of designing any REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Logic on data is mainly put on the views. You can use any views, be it functional, generic API views, and viewsets. There are three types of views in DRF.

You should be comfortable in using one of them, however should understand all of them. Go through this link.
https://micropyramid.com/blog/generic-functional-based-and-class-based-views-in-django-rest-framework/

I personally find comfort in using CBV (Class-Based Views). It is in the views where most of the SQL joins take place too.

For eg:

```
class GetReviewAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Review.objects.filter(user=user)
```

The above is a good example of CBV where the API call gets all the reviews of a particular user only. There is a SQL join happening between the User table and Review table.

Also, you can write the logic in the serializer class as well instead of view. This is done mainly when you have to write the logic for each serializer field differently and set characteristics for each field. I can give you an example for this as well if you want.

Comment: But if the Logic is of say, 40-50 lines, then putting it in views is not efficient.

Comment: No of lines is not the issue. I have written 50+ lines of if else logic for filtering api and it works fine and efficient. The main thing is the requirement. You may write your logic either in view or in serializer class according to your need and business logic.